The Specifics of a Continuous Spectrum
An important distinction within quantum physics is that of discrete and continuous values. For example, much of the various spectra are composed of quantized energy shifts, creating ultimately discrete spectra. However, there does exist true continuous spectra. The example I want to focus on is that of the Sun's emissions. I understand that black body radiation plays an important role in the production of this continuous spectrum, but I want to know why. Can anyone help provide an in-depth explanation of this process, or link me to materials that do?
Greatest point of confusion: I struggle to understand the theory between what a blackbody actually is. The commonly used term of an idealized object provides no clarity.

More on EM radiation & discrete spectrum.

Spectra are always discrete. In theory. All EM radiation is generated by the excitation and subsequent relaxation of subatomic particles. Either by reflection at the surface of the emitter, or by dissipation in the interior.
Small deviation: If you prevent the reflection by

the deepest black for painting a body and
analyze the EM radiation through a hole from the inside of the body
then you have blackbody radiation. No reflection, full dissipation.


As you may know, the search for chemical elements from space using their spectra is made more difficult by the fact that these spectra are frequency-shifted depending on the temperature of the emitting body. However, this does not change the fact that the emitted photons are discrete energy packets. In this sense, all spectra are discrete.
